# C programming heap buffer overflow

Tags: c, tree, buffer, overflow, heap-memory

I just started coding and have a beginner question. So I have a Binary tree. After I add the first node to it, I would like to search the tree see if there are any duplicated node with the same value. But I keep getting error when I try to search the tree which has only one node:
Here is my node:

```
struct node{
int data;
struct node* left;
struct node* right;};
```

Here's the function I used to create the first node

```
struct node* createnode(int num){
struct node *p=malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
p->data=num;
return p;
}
```

And I added It like this:

```
struct node *root;
root=createnode(b);
```

Here is the search function

```
char * search(int num, struct node *p, int dep){
dep=1;
char *result="n";
if(p==NULL){result="n";return result;}
struct node * root;
root=p;
while(root!=NULL){
if(num==root->data){
result= "y";break;
}
if(num>root->data && root->right!=NULL){
root=root->right;dep++;
}
if(num<root->data&&root->left!=NULL){
root=root->left;dep++;
}
if(num >root->data&&root->right==NULL){
result= "n";break;
}
if(num <root->data&&root->left==NULL){
result="n";break;
}
} 
return result;
       }
```

Here is the error I got

```
==6841== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address        0x60040000e000 at pc 0x400eb5 bp 0x7fff3d5302c0 sp 0x7fff3d5302b0
READ of size 8 at 0x60040000e000 thread T0
#0 0x400eb4 (/.autofs/ilab/ilab_users/xy139/night+0x400eb4)
#1 0x402911 (/.autofs/ilab/ilab_users/xy139/night+0x402911)
#2 0x7f2196abdb14 (/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so+0x21b14)
#3 0x400a78 (/.autofs/ilab/ilab_users/xy139/night+0x400a78)
0x60040000e000 is located 8 bytes to the right of 8-byte region  [0x60040000dff0,0x60040000dff8)
allocated by thread T0 here:
#0 0x7f2196e74129 (/usr/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0+0x16129)
#1 0x402071 (/.autofs/ilab/ilab_users/xy139/night+0x402071)
#2 0x402899 (/.autofs/ilab/ilab_users/xy139/night+0x402899)
#3 0x7f2196abdb14 (/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so+0x21b14)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
0x0c00ffff9bb0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c00ffff9bc0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c00ffff9bd0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c00ffff9be0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c00ffff9bf0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 00 fa
=>0x0c00ffff9c00:[fa]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c00ffff9c10: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c00ffff9c20: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c00ffff9c30: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c00ffff9c40: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c00ffff9c50: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
Addressable:           00
Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
Heap left redzone:     fa
Heap righ redzone:     fb
Freed Heap region:     fd
Stack left redzone:    f1
Stack mid redzone:     f2
Stack right redzone:   f3
Stack partial redzone: f4
Stack after return:    f5
Stack use after scope: f8
Global redzone:        f9
Global init order:     f6
Poisoned by user:      f7
ASan internal:         fe
==6841== ABORTING
```

I Thank everyone who are willing to help!!!!

Comment: Don't forget to set the two pointers to null in the node creation function.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
```

You need to allocate enough memory for the struct itself, not a pointer to struct.

```
struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

It is easier to remember to do this if you de-reference the target pointer and pass its size to `malloc` as an argument like so:

```
struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

If you were to change the data type of p in a later revision of a program, then you would not be required to update respective arguments to `malloc`.

Comment: OMG thank you soooo much it worked! Can't believe the assignment I spent a couple days on almost went wasted because of such little mistake, Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

One of the typical errors is allocating the memory not for the size of the structure, but for the pointer to it. [Synchronizer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7361580/synchronizer) showed the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42128294/7538586) of the problem in his answer:

```
struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

I should also add, that malloc can return a potentially null pointer ([link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)), that's why after allocating the memory it should be checked against null before dereference:

```
struct node* createnode(int num)
{
  struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if (p != NULL)                                // <=
  {
    p->data = num;
  }
  return p;
}
```

It's such a pity that it took so much time to find the error. Perhaps, using static analyzers could help to find bugs earlier. [Here](http://www.viva64.com/en/examples/v568/) you can see how a similar mistake can be made in big projects.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the throughout answer which is really helpful! I wonder if the malloc function can return a potentially null pointer, how can I create a node and add a certain value to its data if the pointer is null? If I allocate memory for the node that i defined, should the memory include all the things that I defined for that node?

Comment: The `malloc` returns a null pointer only in bad circumstances. This situation may arise in the case of lack of memory, or perhaps the memory is too fragmented, and you can not get a linear chunk of memory. Therefore, it is important to check the pointer after memory allocation, because the null pointer dereference leads to [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). If the memory was allocated (the size of the `node` in your case), after casting `void` pointer to the `node` pointer all structure fields will be available for work.

Comment: Got it, Thank you!